# How can I do ErrorDocument 404 to /../index.php (parent directory)?

Tags: .htaccess, parent

if a user goes to URL: `http://domain.com/folder/page.php?error=404` (which does not exist)

**How can I have the .htaccess redirect to one folder up** `http://domain.com/page.php?error=404`.

I have been using `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` to redirect to it's index page, but I can't find how to reference its parent folder?

Thanks!

EDIT: I should also mention I'm interested if there is a way other than mod rewrite rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

It works if I do `ErrorDocument 404 /`

Then anything in that folder will redirect to the root folder in this case. I'm not sure if it works for going more than one folder up, or to the direct parent folder. But this worked for me since I need to go to the root, which was one folder up.